# Limiting a transitive dependency to runtime scope in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

I've got 2 projects using Maven. The first one is a library containing utility classes and methods. The second project is an actual application that has the library as a dependency. My library uses internally a third-party library.

So these are the dependencies:

- My library: depends on the third-party library
- My application: depends on my library

However, I don't want the third-party library classes to be available at **compile time** in my application. This is because the application is supported by a large team and I want to prevent people from accidentally using methods from the third-party library in the application given that some class names and some method names are similar between the two. Of course the third-par ty library will have to be available in my application at **runtime**.

If the scope for all my dependencies was **compile**, it wouldn't achieve my goal. Is there a way to achieve this in Maven 3?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Very good question and unfortunately you can't do this using Maven 3, or 2, or any other version, because of its fundamental design. What you're asking about is actually a desired and ideal behaviour since in fact any artifact's `compile` dependencies should be transitive with `runtime` scope. However, design like this leads to some problems. As you can read at [Maven's Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) about `compile` scope:

> It is intended that [transitive dependencies of a compile dependency which are themselves compile dependencies should be considered] runtime scope instead, so that all
>   compile dependencies must be explicitly listed - however, there is the
>   case where the library you depend on extends a class from another
>   library, forcing you to have available at compile time. For this
>   reason, compile time dependencies remain as compile scope even when
>   they are transitive.

So, as you see, what you require is actually the proper design of this behaviour which is unfortunately impossible to implement.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do it. Thanks for your answer, Michal.

Comment: This was answered years ago.  Is there any way to do this now?  I'm wondering if you could somehow use a scope of `import` to hack a solution here?

Comment: I don't think anything changed here. As I said back in 2012, it's very fundamental Maven design. I believe there is no way now to change this since it's just how Maven do things from the very beginning.

Comment: Would it be possible to check that compiled classes only depend on directly specified compile dependencies and have maven error out if these compiled classes depend on classes outside the specified compile dependencies?

Comment: If you know what you're doing,you can override the intented behaviour with `dependencyManagement`, see other answer.

Answer (score 8):

Nothing has changed during the last three years, so Michal's answer is still correct: There is no way to limit transitive visibility in Maven.

However, you should consider redesigning your library to split it in an api-artifact that is necessary as compile time dependency and which itself does not depend on the third party library and an implementation artifact which is only needed as runtime-dependency and which depends on the third party library.

Answer (score 3):

In your application, you can declare an explicit dependency on the third-party library using "runtime" scope.

This prevents the third-party library from being seen at compile time and thus no direct usages can sneak in.  However, it will still be present at run time (since it is needed by your library).

This works, but is awkward and deserves an explanatory XML comment in the pom.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct. Besides working around around a missing crucial feature in maven by splitting out an artificial API-only module, you also have these alternatives:

- exclude the transitive dependencies, then depend on them directly (you have to manage the version numbers yourself)
- Use checkstyle import control, and CI. That way team members may use the transitives, but then maven verify will fail
- Use gradle. This is a solution to many limitations of Maven

Comment: How would Gradle solve the problem when your library subclasses a class from the 3rd party library you're trying to exclude at compile time?

Comment: I believe you would need the superclass at compile time of the application if the subclass was used, else the compiler would fail to compile. So nothing for Gradle to solve here.

Comment: Gradle does solve the issue with the 'implementation' scope. In Gradle 'api' scope behaves like Maven 'compile'. When a library uses a dependency with the 'implementation' scope, the dependency will be available during compilation, but will be published as a 'runtime only' dependency for the consumers of the library

Answer (score 3):

What seems to work is use `<dependencyManagement>` section in the pom.
You will want to check for any side effects, since it works project wide. And you have to specify each library specifically.

Following code sample allowed me to force guava (which was smurfed in the project by google guice as a compile time transitive dependency) to a runtime dependency everywhere.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can analyze dependencies with: `mvn dependency:analyze` or have the dependencies analyzed as part of the verify lifecycle phase:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/failing-the-build-on-dependency-analysis-warnings.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try like that:

```
#My application pom.xml
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>My groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>My library</artifactId>
            <version>${version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>third-party library</groupId>
                    <artifactId> third-party library</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>third-party library</groupId>
            <artifactId> third-party library</artifactId>
            <version>${version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible for you to migrate from Maven to Gradle you can have this issue solved, as pointed out by @tkruse. I'll explain why:

With Gradle, library authors have 2 different "compile" level scopes available:  `api` and `implementation`.

The `api` scope behaves like Maven's `compile` scope and is meant for dependencies of your library that will be part of its API and are thus required to be also "compile" dependencies of the consumers of your lib.

The `implementation` scope however aims to solve the very problem you presented. Its meant for dependencies of your library that are not part of its API and thus only required to be "runtime" dependencies of the consumers of your lib.

*This is done in a very clever way: `implementation` dependencies are used during compilation phase normally, but when Gradle generates the `pom.xml` metadata of the library (or any other type of metadata) to be published, it sets this dependency as a "runtime" dependency.*

Source: [https://gradle.org/maven-vs-gradle](https://gradle.org/maven-vs-gradle/#:~:text=As%20a%20library%20producer%2C%20Gradle%20allows%20producers%20to%20declare%20%60api%60%20and%20%60implementation%60%20dependencies%20to%20prevent%20unwanted%20libraries%20from%20leaking%20into%20the%20classpaths%20of%20consumers)